# How can I select data as JSON using a sub query with a string literal?

Tags: postgresql, json

I am trying to write a query that will transform the data into JSON and can't seem to get it right.

I have two table, Configuration & Provider. Configuration has a FK to provider.id.

This is my query:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
    from (
      select orgid, host, port,
        concat('{Id: ', p.id, '}') as "provider"
      from configurations c
      inner join providers p on
        c.providerid = p.id
    ) t
```

The result looks like below; Notice the 'provider' property has the quotes around the whole value; I need it to be a valid JSON object, not a string.

```
 {
    "orgid": "00Do0000000aOu8ACA",
    "host": "https://somehost.com",
    "port": 5000,
    "provider": "{Id: 12345}"
 }
```

What I want:

```
 {
    "orgid": "00Do0000000aOu8ACA",
    "host": "https://somehost.com",
    "port": 5000,
    "provider": {"Id": "12345"}
 }
```

I feel like I'm close, but can't seem to get it. I've tried using the || operators as well, but can't get that working either. I tried searching for an answer to this, but it's kind of a hard question to convey without a sample. Hopefully this make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just cast it to `json`, putting in the obviously missing quotes

```
concat('{"Id": ', p.id, '}')::json as "provider"
```

But it's better to use a proper function that does this

```
json_build_object('Id', p.id) as "provider"
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8UbbjJ3j)